# set and get method not working as planned

Tags: java, multithreading, get, set

I'm simply trying to send a message to another object but its not exactly changing unless I'm missing a important factor. I have one class to set the number and another class which gets, the class that gets is dependent on the correct number being set however although the set method returns 0 one the command line, the other object returns 1 when using the get method. This is the close class whihc holds both of the methods, each method is called from class A and Class B

```
public class Close {
    static int close =1;

    public synchronized void setClose(int x, Client)
    {
        /*
        while(turn !=0){
            try{
                wait();

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }*/
        close = x;
        System.out.println("set "+close);
    }

    public synchronized int getClose(ClientHandeler)
    {
        int x;
        /*
        while(turn==0){
            try{
                wait();
            }catch(Exception e)
            }
        }*/
        System.out.println("get "+close);
        x = close;
        return x;
    }

}
```

This is the handler class in which i wish to get the close integer from

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ClientHandler implements Runnable {

private BufferedReader reader;
private Socket sock;//refering to socket class
//listens for the socket
private Server server; // call-back reference to transmit message to all clients
Client c = new Client();

public ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket, Server serv) {

    try {
            sock = clientSocket;
            server = serv;

            InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
            reader = new BufferedReader(isReader);



     } catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
     }
}

public void run() {

    String message;




    try {

         int x = c.c.getClose(this);
         while(x!=0){
         x = c.c.getClose(this);//calls client and within client there is the close 
            System.out.println(x);

            Thread ct= Thread.currentThread();
            ct.sleep(3000);
            while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println("read " + message);

                server.tellEveryone(message);
            }
        }       
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}





}
```

Comment: I would have posted the same answer as AlexWien and FloatingCoder.
Try declaring static int close = 1;

Comment: Thanks for adding more code, this is helpful. However, I don't see where setClose is called? Also, in your text you said "set method returns 0" but setClose does not return anything? (Return type is void) Do you mean the output from the println statement is 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably they both do not use the same Close object.

```
Close close = new Close();
```

Then make sure that both use the same close object!

If that is not possible, field close can be made static:

```
  public class Close {
static int close;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use an AtomicInteger.

```
public class Close {
AtomicInteger close = new AtomicInteger(1);

public void setClose(int x)
{
    /*
    while(turn !=0){
    try{
        wait();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/

    close.set(x);
    System.out.println("set "+close.get());   
}
public int getClose()
{
    int x;
    /*
    while(turn==0){
        try{
            wait();
        }catch(Exception e)
    }*/
    System.out.println("get "+close.get());
    x = close.get();
    return x;


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
static int close = 1;
```

This way there will only be one copy of the int close, for all instances of the Close class. Adding the code where you use this class would help, I'm guessing that you are instantiating new copies for each operation, which is causing your issues.

Comment: making the integer static doesn't help, i've tried that as well as using the same object for both and I still have issue where it doesn't seem to get the right integer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your problem.  May you give a little snippet on how you are using this class?

However, it look very likely that you are not accessing the same instance form your so-called class A and B.

It is just like A is writing something on one paper, and B is reading ANOTHER piece of paper.  Of course things written by A is not readable by B.